# I've created a store view (different language) but I receive "There was no 404 CMS page configured or found." when changing language

Tags: store-view, language

I have a store with 3 different languages (EN,DE & FR) and I have installed the language packs for those and I can verify the installation is correct as "app/" has appeared on the file system.

I have then created a store view for each of those languages but 'FR' gives the error "There was no 404 CMS page configured or found." when changing language while viewing a product and I also get that error on both 'FR' and 'DE' when looking at the stores front page.

Have I missed a configuration option somewhere?

Stephen,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ste,you need set cms page  for this store. got `admin>CMS>Page>Select you cms page  and select Store View`  all All storeview or select `desire store for this cms`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under `System > Configuration`, you can see `Design` tab. In that page, you can see a section to set Default pages. There you need to set default home page for each store view that you have created.