# Magento CMS -> Pages not showing Store View selection

Tags: cms, 404

Recently i have discovered a problem in one of my magento websites.
When i try to create new CMS page, there are no Store View selection. So in result when i create it, i can't access it in frontend. I get 404 error. Does anyone faced this problem, and know how to fix it?

Comment: The information in this similar question might help you.

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33587/ive-created-a-store-view-different-language-but-i-receive-there-was-no-404-c

Comment: can you  please share a screen shot\

Comment: [Screen Shot](http://s12.postimg.org/ywh2q8v19/screen.png)

Comment: I have like 6 different store views. And as you can see in screen shot, there is no selection for store view.